# Binding converter to XAML in windows phone 8 app

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

**my .xaml page code**:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="MVVM1Test.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:MVVM1Test.Resources.Converters"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <converter:NotConverter x:Name="not"></converter:NotConverter>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Gray">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    </Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

**notconverter.cs**

```
namespace MVVM1Test.Resources.Converters
{
    public class NotConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return !(bool)value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return !(bool)value;
        }
    }
}
```

it is showing an error

> "the name NotConverter does not exists in the namespace clr-namespace:MVVM1Test.Resources.Converters"

But i have added the converter class also to the solution.

Answer (score 2):

When you place items in a resource dictionary, you must give them keys. The `x:Name` property is redundant (unless you need to access the object from code behind).

```
<converter:NotConverter x:Key="not" />
```

Also, the error you're getting could be a design-time problem. Try to compile and run after the change I suggested.

Comment: Compiling the project helps !

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

xmlns:MyAppConverters="clr-namespace:MyApp.Converters"

and

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <MyAppConverters:CustomConverter x:Key="customConverter"/>    
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

I have given the example you can change the class name as yours

Comment: this i have already added to my xaml file as :
xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:MVVM1Test.Resources.Converters"

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar name space problem. For me, restarting visual studio seemed to solve the problem. Ofcourse, you must ensure the namespace is correctly defined in your IValueConverter Class 
e.g namespace MVVM1Test.Resources.Converters

Save and restart visual studio.