# How to bind xml image in listbox in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-8

How to bind xml image in windows phone 8?
I have done all methods but its not working, Whenever I debug the application, it contains source of an Image but, image is not displaying.

Code:

```
List<LIST> lst = new List<LIST>();
lst = (from query in doc.Descendants("row") select new LIST 
  { Id = Convert.ToInt64(query.Element("Id").Value), 
    Icon = query.Element("Icon").Value, 
    xyz = Convert.ToInt64(query.Element("xyz").Value), 
    Url = query.Element("Url").Value, Name = query.Element("Name").Value }).ToList();    
listBox1.DataContext = lst;
```

XAML Code:

```
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                      

                        <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="50" Width="50" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: " _I have done all methods but not working_ "
Please post in question that what you done..

Comment: List<LIST> lst = new List<LIST>();
lst = (from query in doc.Descendants("row")
   select new LIST
    {  Id = Convert.ToInt64(query.Element("Id").Value),
                             Icon = query.Element("Icon").Value,
                             xyz = Convert.ToInt64(query.Element("xyz").Value),
                             Url = query.Element("Url").Value,
                             Name = query.Element("Name").Value
                         }).ToList();

            listBox1.DataContext = lst;

Comment: How are you binding the image? Do you check whether it is a proper URL??

Comment: What do you mean by xml image? you can save image from xml...it's just text so you have image path is your xml?

Comment: @user3115090 You can edit your quesitions - I've put your code from comment to question - it is more readable.

Comment: @user3115090 Can you also show XAML code?

Comment: here is my XAML code:

Comment: @Romasz I have edited my question and see my XAML code,
Thanks and please help me, I am stuck here.

Comment: hey @RomasZ is it necessary to save xml image in my local pc??
is it the problem??
if yes, give ur suggestions.

Comment: @user3115090 No it's not the problem. You should [provide valid ImageSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.image.source(v=vs.105).aspx). I'm not sure what you get from your Database if you get bytes then you will probably have to use a Converter along with your binding. The converter then will return for example BitmapImage.

Comment: would you like to see my source??

Comment: 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

Comment: @Romasz give me suggestions or links of Converter method.
Thanks!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is my .cs file:

```
public static BitmapImage getImage(string img)
{
    byte[] filebytes = Convert.FromBase64String(img);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(filebytes, 0, filebytes.Length);
    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
    image.SetSource(ms);
    return image;
}

Icon = getImage(query.Element("Icon").Value);
```

and XAML file:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Icon}" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="50" Width="50" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

Comment: this is surely working method. I got the solution
I have converted base64 string to BitMap image

Comment: IMO It will be much better to use a Converter or Property with specified getter. Then it can be easily implemented with INotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try to use a Converter (if you search internet for Binding and Converter, you will find many links, tutorials etc.). A simple code can look like this (I haven't tried it):

In XAML:

```
...
xmlns:common="clr-namespace:YourNamespace"
...
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <common:ToImageSource x:Key="converter"/>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
...
<Image Source="{Binding Icon, Converter={StaticResource converter} }" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="50" Width="50" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

In .cs:

```
public class ToImageSource : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {       
     if (value == null) return null;
     else
     {
        byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(value);

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length))
        {
          stream.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
          BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
          bitmap.SetSource(stream);
          return bitmap;
        }         
     }
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {   // implement ConvertBack      }
}
```

You can also read more about binding and converters [at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207023%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: thnks for help bro but where should I write that code phoneapplicationpage.resources etc.
I am not able to get it

Comment: @user3115090 xmlns: - you add in your Page.xaml at the top between other xmlns. phoneapplicationpage.resources  you add for example after this block (before Grid) [here example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510556/binding-converter-to-xaml-in-windows-phone-8-app). You should also read [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/cc278072(v=vs.105).aspx) and probably some [more tutorials](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/talking-about-converters-in-wp7--coding4fun-toolkit-converters-in-depth).

Comment: i know that brother but I am not able to get "Common" between application resources tag, in my XAML designer.
I am using visual studio 2013, windows phone 8

Comment: @user3115090 Is there a possibility that you share your xaml and cs file?

Comment: I got the solution @Romasz. My web service respnse of xml image was Base64, so I convert base64 to bitmap image and I got the Icon.
Thanks!!

Comment: @user3115090 So it means that my code was correct. I'm glad you have found a solution. Good luck.