# Binding items in ListBox in WP8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, listbox

In a Windows Phone 8 app, 
I have a listbox with 2 TextBlocks and a button.
I have a list of 2 strings and a boolean & I am able to bind the strings to the TextBlocks.

```
<ListBox Name="ListboxTest">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            <Button />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And this is the C# code to bind to the list box.

```
public class Detail
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public bool check { get; set; }
}
public List<Detail> ClassList = new List<Detail>();
ListboxTest.ItemsSource = ClassList;
```

I want to display the button only when the boolean value is true.
How do I do it?

Comment: Can you share the XAML?

Comment: @bit I have added the xaml code.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207023%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). Actually what you really need is a **Converter** by implementing the **IValueConverter**. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510556/binding-converter-to-xaml-in-windows-phone-8-app) is also a good example where you could read about it. Bind the boolean value with the visibility property of the button and you are done! ;)

Comment: I don't think IValueConverter has any effect on the visibility of the button.

Comment: @SundaraRajanC in the following example as **NguyenKien** wrote you see exactly how the interface **IValueConverter** is implemented.

Comment: But @SundaraRajanC it would be better if you read in the first of the links that I send you to understand what a converter is and does.

Answer (score 1):

You can use boolean to visibility converter to hide, show button
Here are example:

```
public class BoolToVisibility : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var boolValue = false;
            if (value != null) boolValue = (bool)value;
            return boolValue ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

In app.xaml

```
<my:BoolToVisibility x:Key="BoolToVisibility"/>
```

In your data template

```
<Button Visibility="{Binding Path=YourBoolProperty,Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}>
```

Comment: in my case, it will be Binding Path=check, right? [where check is of type bool, refering the code shared in the question ]

Answer (score 1):

Please try those use Triggers.

Various Triggers in windows phone [Msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh134799(v=expression.40).aspx).

Please use [ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) in WP8 for binding instead of List.

Please make your properties are implemented with [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) If your Boolean property is not implemented with inotifypropertychanged the view will not know the value is changed.hence the Data trigger will not work.

**Namespace**

```
  xmlns:interactivity="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"

  xmlns:ec="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions" 
x:Class="XXX_XXXX"

<Button Content="My button"
               Stretch="None"
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
               VerticalAlignment="Top">

                                <interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
                <ec:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Check}" Value="True">
                    <ec:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Visibility">
                        <ec:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                        </ec:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                    </ec:ChangePropertyAction>
                </ec:DataTrigger>

                <ec:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Check}" Value="False">
                    <ec:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Visibility">
                        <ec:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                            <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                        </ec:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                    </ec:ChangePropertyAction>
                </ec:DataTrigger>

            </interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Button>
```

*Note Answered from phone syntax may not be correct*

Answer (score 1):

Or, you could add this property to the `Detail` class:

```
public Visibility ButtonVisibility {
    get {
        return this.check == true ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

And then just bind the button's `Visibility` to the `ButtonVisibility` property without any converters.

```
<Button Visibility="{Binding ButtonVisibility}" />
```